# Effect on ECU on turbo install on N/A engine

Tags: engine, turbocharger

I own a Suzuki Swift M13A non VVTI, it have both MAP and MAF sensor, Its N/A engine with compression ratio 9.5:1. I want to install a turbo on it with 0.5 bar boost. I would like to know if MAP and MAF sensors are able to give accurate readings to the ECU? Would they manage A/F ratio automatically? Also I just have read that in boosted engines location of MAP sensor is between the turbo and the throttle body, Whereas in a N/A engine it is located on the intake manifold. Will it work if I change the location of MAP sensor? I want to do all work by myself, so need advice on this.

Comment: Hi, I think it would work changing the sensor to the other location. But I'm concerned about other stuff like timming. Have wrapped your head around stuff like that?

Comment: You will need an ecu that has the characteristic maps adjusted for the effect of the turbo, ie fuel delivery, timing etc Do you have the equipment to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Stock ECU's for N/A motors, are not mapped to read pressure above a few pounds over vacuum.
The sensors will give the proper signal but the ECU is not programed to handle it.

If you were going to use low boost you could get away with using MAF sensor with a rising rate fuel pressure regulator and something like a superAFC.

However you are going over 5-7 psi with your 14.7 psi or 1 bar. You are going to want to get a map sensor based fuel controller. Like the AEM F/IC, this will take care of the fuel and spark timing for that higher boost and it has the MAP sensor built in. This will not throw an engine light if installed correctly. I have used this on an 01 tiburon for 3 years with no engine light.

Using the AEM F/IC

The stock map sensor location remains the same

The Map on the AEM would be piped to the 3-way hose barb between the compressor housing and the wastegate.

The MAF and stock MAP wires would be intercepted and caped at around 4.8 volts by the AEM.

The idea here being when not on boost the stock ECU is running everything directly. On boost the AEM intercepts and conditions the stock signals while adding fuel and subtracting timing behind the scenes.

Comment: One mistake from me, I want below 0.5 bar boost, about 6psi,

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Chip-Tuning-Box-for-SUZUKI-Swift-III-1-3-66kW-90HP-2005-2010-Petrol-CS2/254001078648?hash=item3b23a4e178:g:t48AAOSwYIpb~So1

Comment: Could this thing work for low boost

Comment: 6psi is gauge pressure, stock ecu's are designed to read around atmospheric pressure, that is about 14.7psi absolute...

Comment: I dont have much knowledge, but according to my search, if we give 0.5 bar boost, it is added to that 1 bar(14.7), means it totally become 20 psi, I am not sure, clear me if I am wrong